# How to add to an element in char Array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I want to know how to add a value to an element of an array. This is not a duplicate as i don't want to add a new elemnt or assign an entirely new value but want to edit an existing value in the array. I'd imagine it would look something like this:

```
textArray[i] = currentElement + variable;
```

The example above does for some reason not work though

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: You can try it yourself, do you face some problem?

Comment: `textArray[i] = textArray[i] + variable;`

Comment: The example I gave does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `textArray[i] += variable;` or the more verbose `textArray[i] = textArray[i] + variable;`. In the second version note that the right hand side of `=` is *fully* evaluated before the assignment is made to `textArray[i]`.

In this sense `textArray[i]` can be used both to "get" and "set" a value of an element in the array.

Just make sure that `i` is a valid array index in advance.

Comment: Thank you. This does work but is there another way? My profs don't seem to like "+=" method at all.

Comment: Well they should! I've put in the verbose alternative.

Comment: Alright. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the SetValue method as below. `textArray.SetValue(1,1);` where first parameter is the element and second element is the index.

Comment: but I want to add to an existing element not replace it with another value. For example: if the value of the array at index 1 is 2, I'd want to add 3 to it so that the value of the element is now 5